# Close the browser window using javascript, when the window has been opened by form tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp-classic

I am using form tag to open a new window using the code,

```
<form action="/xxx/yyy.asp?ax=12345&amp;bx=56432146" method="post" target="_blank">
        <input type="submit" value="Open Test" class="btn-yellow ie-fix" id="btn-confirm">
</form>
```

It opens new window with query strings ax and bx, Now i just want to close this window using javascript/Angularjs.

to close the window i used,

```
window.close();
```

but it didn't work.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can only close functions which has been created by you using `window.open()`.

In this case, you can use it for closing window:

```
var win = window.open('stackoverflow.com');
win.close();
```

In other cases, it looks like you cannot do this.

Comment: That's the function the OP said they were using in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The new window is opened by `target="_blank"` attribute which cannot be closed using `window.close()` or `close()` as `window` is a global object.

Probably you should try using AJAX. Send a POST request to the URL used in form and in `success` callback use `window.open()` to pop up a new window.

Also, make sure to store an instance of window opened as it have to be used later to close the window as `win.close()` were `win` is the variable storing instance created using `window.open()` method.

Including jQuery based AJAX as sample. You may try with AngularJS.

References:

1. [jQuery AJAX API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
2. [Window - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)

Comment: Is there any other way to close it.